# in R how do i get mapply to ignore the NA on elements passed to the function

Tags: r, mapply

I created a simple function to determine the difference between 2 variables in a dataframe

```
 detYearDisc <- function(x,y)
 {
    if (x < y)
          return("L")
    if (x > y)
          return("G")
    if (x == y) 
          return("N")

}
```

The dataframe df can contain NA on x or y or both . When I run the mapply function

```
df$DiscInd = mapply(detYearDisc, df$X,df$Y)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (x < y) return("L") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is this because I got NA on x or y value??

Comment: Why `mapply()`? Why not a nested and vectorized `ifelse()`?

Comment: @Parfait , i tried that and I was getting nowhere so I decided to switch implementation

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reason is that either of them has `NA` value. See the followings:

```
mapply(detYearDisc, 1,2)
#[1] "L"
mapply(detYearDisc, 2,2)
#[1] "N"
mapply(detYearDisc, 2,1)
#[1] "G"
mapply(detYearDisc, 2,NA)
#Error in if (x < y) return("L") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

To handle it, you can add the following as the first line in your function:

```
if (is.na(x) | is.na(y))
    return("Not a number!")
```

However, you can achieve the same with this simple `ifelse` in a vectorized manner:

```
ifelse(df$x>df$y, "G", ifelse(df$x<df$y, "L", "N"))
```

In case of `NA`, it will return `NA`. E.g. for:

```
df
   x y
1  1 5
2  3 0
3  5 1
4 NA 4
```

Will give you:

```
[1] "L" "G" "G" NA
```

Alternatively, thanks to @alistaire for pointing out `case_when` from the `dplyr` package, you could also do:

```
f <- function(x,y){
case_when(
    (is.na(x) | is.na(y)) ~ "NA",
    x>y ~ "G",
    x<y ~ "L",
    TRUE ~ "N"
)}
```

So, you would get the same result by calling the function `f(df$x, df$y)`.

Comment: @moh3n if I use the ifelse, would it be able to handle the NA occurrence?

Comment: @EB yes, in such a case it will return `NA`.

Comment: so do I just use use the  function as :    df$DiscInd = f(df$X,df$Y)) with the dplyr implementation ...

Comment: Yes, that's all. Or with `ifelse` you write `df$DiscInd <- ifelse(df$x>df$y, "G", ifelse(df$x<df$y, "L", "N"))`.